# Curl to return http status code along with the response

Tags: shell, curl

I use curl to get http headers to find http status code and also return response. I get the http headers with the command

```
curl -I http://localhost
```

To get the response, I use the command

```
curl http://localhost
```

As soon as use the -I flag, I get only the headers and the response is no longer there. Is there a way to get both the http response and the headers/http status code in in one command?

Comment: Here's a very useful snippet
https://gist.github.com/maxcnunes/9f77afdc32df354883df

Answer (score 364, accepted):

I was able to get a solution by looking at the curl doc which specifies to use `-` for the output to get the output to stdout.

```
curl -o - -I http://localhost
```

To get the response with just the http return code, I could just do

```
curl -o /dev/null -s -w "%{http_code}\n" http://localhost
```

Comment: or you'd use `-i`. Or perhaps `-v` if you like some additional info too.

Comment: Removing the `-I` switch meant the headers and status are no longer part of the output of the first command. `-o -` is the default, and you only need it if _some other switch_ like `-I` disabled the response body output. I added it back in.

Comment: appending to the later retun code only  with  " | -grep -q 401 " makes for a nice healthcheck without actual auth creds.

Comment: it didnt work for my post request:  Warning: You can only select one HTTP request method! You asked for both POST 
Warning: (-d, --data) and HEAD (-I, --head).

Comment: According to the official curl documentation (https://everything.curl.dev/usingcurl/verbose/writeout), `http_code` has been replaced by `response_code`.

Answer (score 183):

the verbose mode will tell you everything

```
curl -v http://localhost
```

Comment: don't work for me if the response also have a payload (in my case the status code which was send put not printed out was 503)

Comment: no, this definitely does print out the response body too

Answer (score 124):

I found this question because I wanted independent access to BOTH the response and the content in order to add some error handling for the user.

Curl allows you to customize output. **You can capture the HTTP status code to add a variable and write the contents to another file**.

```
curl -s -o response.txt -w "%{response_code}" http://example.com
```

**This allows you to check the return code and then decide if the response is worth printing**, processing, logging, etc.

```
http_response=$(curl -s -o response.txt -w "%{response_code}" http://example.com)
if [ $http_response != "200" ]; then
    # handle error
else
    echo "Server returned:"
    cat response.txt    
fi
```

The `%{response_code}` (or `%{http_code}` in older versions) is a variable substituted by curl. You can do a lot more, or send code to stderr, etc.  See curl manual and the `--write-out` option.

> -w, --write-out
>
> Make curl display information on stdout after a completed
> transfer. The format is a string that may contain plain
> text mixed with any number of variables. The format can be
> specified as a literal "string", or you can have curl read
> the format from a file with "@filename" and to tell curl
> to read the format from stdin you write "@-".
>
> The variables present in the output format will be
> substituted by the value or text that curl thinks fit, as
> described below. All variables are specified as
> %{variable_name} and to output a normal % you just write
> them as %%. You can output a newline by using \n, a
> carriage return with \r and a tab space with \t.
>
> The output will be written to standard output, but this
> can be switched to standard error by using %{stderr}.

https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/curl.1.html

Comment: what is http_code? I don't understand this, needs more explanation pls

Comment: clarified above, it refers to the HTTP Status code - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status

Comment: Based on this answer and the accepted one to create a bash script, that retries curl calls: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70522459/6344916. Thank you!

Comment: If you run this under Windows via `.bat` file, you might want to escape the percent sign: `-w "%%{http_code}"`

Comment: `http_code` is now renamed as `response_code`

Answer (score 62):

I use this command to print the status code without any other output. Additionally, it will only perform a HEAD request and follow the redirection (respectively `-I` and `-L`).

```
curl -o -I -L -s -w "%{http_code}" http://localhost
```

This makes it very easy to check the status code in a health script:

```
sh -c '[ $(curl -o -I -L -s -w "%{http_code}" http://localhost) -eq 200 ]'
```

Comment: This has already been answered a year ago. What new value does your answer bring? Also please write some explanation to your answer.

Comment: @MaciejJureczko - The value is simple. For scripting purposes, this answer is the best out of all the other answers, because it gives a single status code instead of many lines of garbage along with said status code.

Comment: But the OP specifically states that they want **both** the status code and the response body.  They know how to just get the response code (stated in the question)

Comment: Whenever I use this `curl -o -I -L -s -w "%{http_code}" http://localhost` a file is created called `-I`, to get around this I added a place for the file output implied by `-o` to go, namely `/dev/null`: `curl -o /dev/null -I -L -s -w "%{http_code}" http://localhost`

Comment: HEAD will not always result in same output as a request though, up to the server how they respond. So this is not really an answer.

Comment: single assignment,  code=<back-tick>curl -k -s -o /dev/null -w "%{http_code}" https://www.yuktix.com/robots.txt<back-tick>

Answer (score 50):

The `-i` option is the one that you want:

```
curl -i http://localhost
```

> -i, --include       Include protocol headers in the output (H/F)

Alternatively you can use the verbose option:

```
curl -v http://localhost
```

> -v, --verbose       Make the operation more talkative

Comment: There is a gotcha with `-i` in that you will sometimes receive two sets of HTTP response codes in the output, such as with `HTTP/1.1 100 Continue` headers followed later by a `HTTP/1.1 200 OK` header. You can disable this expect mechanism see https://gms.tf/when-curl-sends-100-continue.html

Answer (score 25):

I have used this :

```
    request_cmd="$(curl -i -o - --silent -X GET --header 'Accept: application/json' --header 'Authorization: _your_auth_code==' 'https://example.com')"
```

To get the HTTP status

```
    http_status=$(echo "$request_cmd" | grep HTTP |  awk '{print $2}')
    echo $http_status
```

To get the response body I've used this

```
    output_response=$(echo "$request_cmd" | grep body)
    echo $output_response
```

Answer (score 23):

This command

```
 curl http://localhost -w ", %{http_code}"
```

will get the comma separated body and status; you can split them to get them out.

You can change the delimiter as you like.

Comment: good hint! 
is it possible to add status code in front of output?

Comment: I found this answer very helpful too. And to answer @Psychozoic's question... I couldn't find a way but adding new line separators helped highlight the response code from the response body and my command prompt appearing on the same lines as the response code. Try this:  `curl http://localhost -w "\nResponse Code: %{http_code}\n"`"

Comment: @benhorgen next answer helps with that, check it!

Answer (score 17):

### To get response code along with response:

```
$ curl -kv https://www.example.org
```

### To get just response code:

```
$ curl -kv https://www.example.org 2>&1 | grep -i 'HTTP/1.1 ' | awk '{print $3}'| sed -e 's/^[ \t]*//'
```

- 2>&1: error is stored in output for parsing
- grep: filter the response code line from output
- awk: filters out the response code from response code line
- sed: removes any leading white spaces

> Note: If using HTTP version 2.0, modify the grep statement as `grep -i 'HTTP/2 '`

Comment: this also prints alot of garbage from the very request while the question is about printing the response alongside the status code

Comment: Its works for `HTTP/1.1`. If using HTTPv2.0, grep statement should be updated to `'HTTP/2'`

Answer (score 14):

This is a way to retrieve the body "AND" the status code and format it to a proper json or whatever format works for you. Some may argue it's the incorrect use of write format option but this works for me when I need both body and status code in my scripts to check status code and relay back the responses from server.

```sh
curl -X GET -w "%{stderr}{\"status\": \"%{http_code}\", \"body\":\"%{stdout}\"}"  -s -o - “https://github.com” 2>&1
```

run the code above and you should get back a json in this format:

```
{
"status" : <status code>,
"body" : <body of response>
}
```

with the -w write format option, since stderr is printed first, you can format your output with the var http_code and place the body of the response in a value (body) and follow up the enclosing using var stdout. Then redirect your stderr output to stdout and you'll be able to combine both http_code and response body into a neat output

Comment: Got the following error - ```curl: unknown --write-out variable: 'stderr'``` and ```curl: unknown --write-out variable: 'stdout'```

Comment: https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html man page shows variable available. not sure why stderr is not recognized by your curl, the curl im on a macbook. From this Linux curl doc, https://www.computerhope.com/unix/curl.htm, I dont see stderr as an variable either. Perhaps this is an OS variation.

Comment: only issue i have with this is if you body has quotation marks, such as if its json, the body will make the json response above invalid json

Comment: fair enough @theannouncer, I would expect the dev to adjust accordingly as not all responses will be standard json. There were some instances I had to adjust due to the nature of the response.

Comment: @ALex_hha Please check your syntax or curl version. Write-out variable stdout is documented here : https://everything.curl.dev/usingcurl/verbose/writeout#available-write-out-variables

Answer (score 11):

For programmatic usage, I use the following :

```
curlwithcode() {
    code=0
    # Run curl in a separate command, capturing output of -w "%{http_code}" into statuscode
    # and sending the content to a file with -o >(cat >/tmp/curl_body)
    statuscode=$(curl -w "%{http_code}" \
        -o >(cat >/tmp/curl_body) \
        "$@"
    ) || code="$?"

    body="$(cat /tmp/curl_body)"
    echo "statuscode : $statuscode"
    echo "exitcode : $code"
    echo "body : $body"
}

curlwithcode https://api.github.com/users/tj
```

It shows following output :

```
statuscode : 200
exitcode : 0
body : {
  "login": "tj",
  "id": 25254,
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 10):

**My way to achieve this**:

To get both (header and body), I usually perform a `curl -D- <url>` as in:

```sh
$ curl -D- http://localhost:1234/foo
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Connection: Keep-Alive
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: application/json
Date: Wed, 29 Jul 2020 20:59:21 GMT

{"data":["out.csv"]}
```

This will dump headers (`-D`) to stdout (`-`) (Look for `--dump-header` in [man curl](https://linux.die.net/man/1/curl)).

IMHO also very handy in this context:

I often use [jq](https://github.com/stedolan/jq) to get that json data (eg from some rest APIs) formatted. But as jq doesn't expect a HTTP header, the trick is to print headers to stderr using `-D/dev/stderr`. Note that this time we also use `-sS` (--silent, --show-errors) to suppress the progress meter (because we write to a pipe).

```sh
$ curl -sSD/dev/stderr http://localhost:1231/foo | jq .
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Connection: Keep-Alive
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: application/json
Date: Wed, 29 Jul 2020 21:08:22 GMT

{
  "data": [
    "out.csv"
  ]
}
```

I guess this also can be handy if you'd like to print headers (for quick inspection) to console but redirect body to a file (eg when its some kind of binary to not mess up your terminal):

```sh
$ curl -sSD/dev/stderr http://localhost:1231 > /dev/null
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Connection: Keep-Alive
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: application/json
Date: Wed, 29 Jul 2020 21:20:02 GMT
```

Be aware: This is NOT the same as `curl -I <url>`! As `-I` will perform a `HEAD` request and not a `GET` request (Look for `--head` in [man curl](https://linux.die.net/man/1/curl). Yes: For most HTTP servers this will yield same result. But I know a lot of business applications which don't implement `HEAD` request at all ;-P

Answer (score 8):

A one-liner, just to get the status-code would be:

```sh
curl -s -i https://www.google.com | head -1
```

Changing it to `head -2` will give the time as well.

---

If you want a while-true loop over it, it would be:

```sh
URL="https://www.google.com"

while true; do
    echo "------"
    curl -s -i $URL | head -2
    sleep 2;
done
```

Which produces the following, until you do `cmd+C` (or `ctrl+C` in Windows).

```
------
HTTP/2 200
date: Sun, 07 Feb 2021 20:03:38 GMT
------
HTTP/2 200
date: Sun, 07 Feb 2021 20:03:41 GMT
------
HTTP/2 200
date: Sun, 07 Feb 2021 20:03:43 GMT
------
HTTP/2 200
date: Sun, 07 Feb 2021 20:03:45 GMT
------
HTTP/2 200
date: Sun, 07 Feb 2021 20:03:47 GMT
------
HTTP/2 200
date: Sun, 07 Feb 2021 20:03:49 GMT
```

Comment: `curl -sSi $URL | head -2 | tr -d '\r' | tr '\n' ' '; echo;` will make it a one-liner output.

Comment: then why not

`curl -L -I -s -f -w "%{http_code}" https://google.com | tail -n1`
200%

`curl -L -I -s -f -w "%{http_code}" https://test.google.com | tail -n1`
000%


`curl -L -I -s -f -w "%{http_code}" https://google.com/aaa | tail -n1`
404%

Comment: @AndriiTishchenko I couldn't run the command(s) you mentioned.

Comment: sorry, there are 3 separate : `curl -L -I -s -f -w "%{http_code}" https://google.com | tail -n1`

Answer (score 8):

### A clear one to read using pipe

```sh
function cg(){
    curl -I --silent www.google.com | head -n 1 | awk -F' ' '{print $2}'
}
cg
# 200
```

Welcome to use my dotfile script [here](https://github.com/QiangZiBro/Qdotfiles/blob/master/ss/proxy.zsh)

### Explanation

- `--silent`: Don't show progress bar when using pipe
- `head -n 1`: Only show the first line
- `-F' '`: separate text by columns using separator space
- `'{print $2}'`: show the second column

Answer (score 5):

Some good answers here, but like the OP I found myself wanting, in a scripting context, all of:

- any response body returned by the server, regardless of the response status-code: some services will send error details e.g. in JSON form when the response is an error
- the HTTP response code
- the `curl` exit status code

This is difficult to achieve with a single `curl` invocation and I was looking for a complete solution/example, since the required processing is complex.

I combined some other bash recipes on multiplexing stdout/stderr/return-code with some of the ideas here to arrive at the following example:

```
{
  IFS= read -rd '' out
  IFS= read -rd '' http_code
  IFS= read -rd '' status
} < <({ out=$(curl -sSL -o /dev/stderr -w "%{http_code}" 'https://httpbin.org/json'); } 2>&1; printf '\0%s' "$out" "$?")
```

Then the results can be found in variables:

```
echo out $out
echo http_code $http_code
echo status $status
```

Results:

```
out { "slideshow": { "author": "Yours Truly", "date": "date of publication", "slides": [ { "title": "Wake up to WonderWidgets!", "type": "all" }, { "items": [ "Why <em>WonderWidgets</em> are great", "Who <em>buys</em> WonderWidgets" ], "title": "Overview", "type": "all" } ], "title": "Sample Slide Show" } }
http_code 200
status 0
```

The script works by multiplexing the output, HTTP response code and `curl` exit status separated by null characters, then reading these back into the current shell/script.  It can be tested with `curl` requests that would return a >=400 response code but also produce output.

Note that without the `-f` flag, `curl` won't return non-zero error codes when the server returns an abnormal HTTP response code i.e. >=400, and with the `-f` flag, server output is suppresses on error, making use of this flag for error-detection and processing unattractive.

Credits for the generic `read` with IFS processing go to this answer: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/430182/45479 .

Answer (score 1):

Append a line "http_code:200" at the end, and then grep for the keyword "http_code:" and extract the response code.

```
result=$(curl -w "\nhttp_code:%{http_code}" http://localhost)

echo "result: ${result}"   #the curl result with "http_code:" at the end

http_code=$(echo "${result}" | grep 'http_code:' | sed 's/http_code://g') 

echo "HTTP_CODE: ${http_code}"  #the http response code
```

In this case, you can still use the non-silent mode / verbose mode to get more information about the request such as the curl response body.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience we usually use curl this way

```sh
curl -f http://localhost:1234/foo || exit 1

curl: (22) The requested URL returned error: 400 Bad Request
```

This way we can pipe the curl when it fails, and it also shows the status code.

Answer (score 1):

### Catch response and status code in 2 different variables and preserve exit code

Solution based on this discussion: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59592881/10693476

Implement catch function:

```bash
catch() {
    {
        IFS=$'\n' read -r -d '' "${1}";
        IFS=$'\n' read -r -d '' "${2}";
        (IFS=$'\n' read -r -d '' _ERRNO_; return ${_ERRNO_});
    } < <((printf '\0%s\0%d\0' "$(((({ shift 2; "${@}"; echo "${?}" 1>&3-; } | tr -d '\0' 1>&4-) 4>&2- 2>&1- | tr -d '\0' 1>&4-) 3>&1- | exit "$(cat)") 4>&1-)" "${?}" 1>&2) 2>&1)
}
```

Example with curl to catch status code (redirected to stderr), response ( on stdout) & exit code:

```bash
$ catch response_data status_code curl -ks -w "%{stderr}%{http_code}" https://host/api/wrong/path
$ echo $?
0
$ echo $status_code 
404
$ echo $response_data 
{"error_type":"NOT_FOUND","messages":[{"args":[],"default_message":"Not found.","id":"api.rest.httpNotFound"}]}
```

Answer (score 1):

This can also be done by using the `--fail-with-body` flag.
It will output the response body to `stdout` and the error message to `stderr`

From curls man page:

```
   --fail-with-body
          (HTTP)  Return  an error on server errors where the HTTP response code is 400 or greater). In normal cases when an HTTP server fails to deliver a document, it returns an HTML document stating
          so (which often also describes why and more). This flag will still allow curl to output and save that content but also to return error 22.

          This is an alternative option to -f, --fail which makes curl fail for the same circumstances but without saving the content.

          Providing --fail-with-body multiple times has no extra effect.  Disable it again with --no-fail-with-body.

          Example:
           curl --fail-with-body https://example.com

          See also -f, --fail. This option is mutually exclusive to -f, --fail. Added in 7.76.0.
```

Example error output:

```bash
$ curl -sS --fail-with-body https://example.com/404 >/dev/null
curl: (22) The requested URL returned error: 404
$ echo $?
22
```

Answer (score 0):

Wow so many answers, cURL devs definitely left it to us as a home exercise :) Ok here is my take - a script that makes the cURL working as it's supposed to be, i.e.:

- show the output as cURL would.
- exit with non-zero code in case of HTTP response code not in 2XX range

Save it as `curl-wrapper.sh`:

---

```
#!/bin/bash

output=$(curl -w "\n%{http_code}" "$@")
res=$?

if [[ "$res" != "0" ]]; then
  echo -e "$output"
  exit $res
fi

if [[ $output =~ [^0-9]([0-9]+)$ ]]; then
    httpCode=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
    body=${output:0:-${#httpCode}}

    echo -e "$body"

    if (($httpCode < 200 || $httpCode >= 300)); then
        # Remove this is you want to have pure output even in 
        # case of failure:
        echo
        echo "Failure HTTP response code: ${httpCode}"
        exit 1
    fi
else
    echo -e "$output"
    echo
    echo "Cannot get the HTTP return code"
    exit 1
fi
```

---

So then it's just business as usual, but instead of `curl` do `./curl-wrapper.sh`:

So when the result falls in 200-299 range:

```
./curl-wrapper.sh www.google.com 
# ...the same output as pure curl would return...
echo $?
# 0
```

And when the result is out of in 200-299 range:

```
./curl-wrapper.sh www.google.com/no-such-page
# ...the same output as pure curl would return - plus the line
#    below with the failed HTTP code, this line can be removed if needed:
#
# Failure HTTP response code: 404
echo $?
# 1
```

**Just do not pass "-w|--write-out" argument since that's what added inside the script**

Answer (score 0):

I used the following way of getting both `return code` as well as `response body` in the console.

NOTE - **use `tee` which append the output into a file as well as to the console, which solved my purpose.**

`Sample CURL call for reference:`

```
curl -s -i -k --location --request POST ''${HOST}':${PORT}/api/14/project/'${PROJECT_NAME}'/jobs/import' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/yaml' \
--header 'X-Rundeck-Auth-Token: '${JOB_IMPORT_TOKEN}'' \
--data "$(cat $yaml_file)" &>/dev/stdout | tee -a $response_file

return_code=$(cat $response_file | head -3 | tail -1 | awk {'print $2'})

if [ "$return_code" != "200" ]; then
  echo -e "\Job import api call failed with rc: $return_code, please rerun or change pipeline script."
  exit $return_code
else
  echo "Job import api call completed successfully with rc: $return_code"
fi
```

Hope this would help a few.

Answer (score 0):

**To capture only response:**
curl --location --request GET "http://localhost:8000" 
**To capture the response and its  statuscode:**
curl --location --request GET "http://localhost:8000" -w "%{http_code}" 
**To capture the response  in a file:**
curl --location --request GET "http://localhost:8000" -s -o "response.txt"

Answer (score -2):

```
while : ; do curl -sL -w "%{http_code} %{url_effective}\\n" http://host -o /dev/null; done
```

Comment: Why would you put this in a while loop? Please expand and explain your answer.

Answer (score -4):

This works for me:

```
curl -Uri 'google.com' | select-object StatusCode
```

Comment: this answer is relevant to powershell's alias for Invoke-WebRequest, not curl.