# Bash - How to get http response body and status code?

Tags: bash, shell, curl

I am trying below code to get response body and status:

```
read -ra result <<< $(curl -i --insecure \
    -H "Accept: application/json" \
    -H "Content-Type:application/json" \
    -X POST --data "$configData" $openingNode"/voice/v1/updateWithPh")
status=${result[1]}
response=${result[@]}
echo $status
```

Problem here is -

I get both status code and response Body correctly. 
But when I create a bash function and send it as an argument, the response body changes to **"HTTP/1.1"** in the function as shown below.

```
echo $(validateUpdate $configData $response)
```

Code for the function -

```
function validateUpdate(){
   echo $1
   echo $2
}
```

$2 prints as **"HTTP/1.1"**

What is the reason? How to rectify this issue?

Comment: Perhaps you have a newline in `$configData`. Can you try to quote your vars: `echo $(validateUpdate "$configData" "$response")`

Comment: Post an example of `${result[@]}`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Curl to return http status code along with the response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38906626/curl-to-return-http-status-code-along-with-the-response)

Answer (score 0):

You need to enclose your variables in double quotes to prevent bash splitting it into separate tokens.

Try

```
echo $(validateUpdate "$configData" "$response")
```

or even better (echo is useless as @tripleee points out; furthermore curly braces improves readability):

```
validateUpdate "${configData}" "${response}"
```

use same thing inside of your function

```
echo "$2"
```

Comment: `echo $(command)` is usually better written `command` unless you specifically *require* the shell to perform whitespace tokenization and wildcard expansion on the output from `command` before printing it.  See also [useless use of `echo`](http://www.iki.fi/era/unix/award.html#echo)

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
RESPONSE=$(curl --request POST \
  --url $URL \
  -w "\n%{http_code}" \
  -s)


RESPONSE_CODE=$(tail -n1 <<< "$RESPONSE")
RESPONSE_BODY=$(sed '$ d' <<< "$RESPONSE")

echo "Response code = ${RESPONSE_CODE}"
echo "Response body = ${RESPONSE_BODY}"
```