# Can I have curl print just the response code?

Tags: http, curl

I read https://superuser.com/questions/272265/getting-curl-to-output-http-status-code . It mentioned that

```
curl -i
```

will print the HTTP response code. Is it possible to have curl print *just* the HTTP response code? Is there a generic way to get the HTTP status code for any type of request like GET/POST/etc?

I am using curl 7.54.0 on Mac OS High Sierra.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Curl to return http status code along with the response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38906626/curl-to-return-http-status-code-along-with-the-response)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
$  curl -s -w "%{http_code}\n" http://google.com/ -o /dev/null
```

Comment: If you prefer longhand param names: `-s` = `--silent`, `-w` = `--write-out`, `-o` = `--output`

Answer (score 2):

```
curl -s -I http://example.org | grep HTTP/ | awk {'print $2'}
```

output: `200`

Comment: Thank you. I read the curl man page. -I will send HEAD request. Is there a generic way to get the HTTP status code for GET/POST/etc?

Comment: but it's rare case, normally it's invoked by using dedicated command line options, for example `--upload-file` for PUT

Answer (score 0):

Another solution:

```bash
curl -sI http://example.org | head -n 1 | cut -d ' ' -f 2
```

in this way you are:

1. getting the first HTTP response line (`head -n 1`), which must contain the response HTTP version, the response code and the response message (in this order), each one separated by a whitespace (as defined in the HTTP standard);
2. getting the 2° field of this line (`cut -d ' ' -f 2`), which is the status code