# Avoiding kinit when cache still has credentials

Tags: linux, kerberos, systemd, mit-kerberos

I have a `systemd` service that calls a webservice to perform some maintenance periodically (every minute). The service looks like:

```
[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/usr/bin/kinit -kt user.keytab user@DOMAIN
ExecStart=/usr/bin/curl --tlsv1.2 --cacert cert.pem --negotiate --user user: --url https://website/maintenance
```

now this destroy and reinitializes my kerberos ticket every time.
the kinit can take up to 2-3 min.

I would like to avoid that step and only `kinit` if needed. any ideas?

Comment: Execute `klist` and grep for the session presence. If it exists then you don't need to re-run kinit.

Comment: thank you. I attempted to write a script for that and it seems to work. see my answer below

Comment: Run `kinit -R` first to renew the existing ticket (should be faster since there's no pwd check) and only if that fails, recreate a fresh ticket with `kinit -kt <keytab>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After researching a bit more, I realized having logic in systemd service didn't seem like a good idea. So I decided to go with the suggestion by [Elliott Frisch](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2970947/elliott-frisch) and create a script for it:

```
#!/bin/bash
# check if ticket is present and not expired
if [[ $(klist -l | awk 'tolower($0) ~ /user/ && tolower($0) !~ /expired/') ]]; then
    echo "using ticket cache"
else
    echo "no cache authentication for user, kinit needed"
    /usr/bin/kinit -kt /user.keytab user@DOMAIN
fi
/usr/bin/curl --tlsv1.2 --cacert cert.pem --negotiate --user user: --url https://website/maintenance
```

I am then calling this script in my systemd service

Answer (score 0):

Try the HTTP request, and use the status code to decide whether you need to try kinit. You could grep the output of curl like this:

```
curl -s -i http://www.example.com | grep "HTTP/" | tail -1
```

If it's "HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized", run kinit and try again. (See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53526188/can-i-have-curl-print-just-the-response-code) for how to parse out just the numeric part of the response if you prefer)

The "tail -1" part is to make sure you only get the last code; because of the negotiate protocol, you will typically get multiple lines from the grep command, like this:

```
HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
```

The first one is the initial challenge from the server; the second one is the final response code.

Comment: thank you, that is good suggestion. however I'd like to avoid an unnecessary call to my webservice, so I am going to go with the other suggestion