# How to retrieve the HTTP code from groovy curl execute method

Tags: rest, http, curl, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I am using groovy execute API in Jenkins pipeline code to execute the curl command, I am getting response from the rest API, but I am not able to retrieve HTTP code.

How to retrieve the HTTP code from groovy curl execute method.

```
node{
    stage("api")
    {
        getApi()
     }


}
def getApi()
{
     def process  = ['bash', '-c',"curl -X GET --header 'Content-Type: application/json' --header 'Accept: application/json' -H 'Authorization: Bearer oosfjwejowjefojwoejfowoefjwojefwefweofjwo' https://myrest.api.com"].execute()
     process.waitFor()
     println (process.err.text)
     println (process.text)
}
```

Comment: What is the "HTTP code" - do you mean the body/result or do you mean the HTTP status code (e.g. 200 or 404)?

Comment: I mean HTTP status code e.g. 200 or 404

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Curl to return http status code along with the response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38906626/curl-to-return-http-status-code-along-with-the-response)

Comment: @cfrick, thanks but  no, is there any to retrieve from the process object of groovy

Comment: @nilesh1212, why not? that's exactly what you need...

Comment: @cfrick : you suggestion worked for me thanks

Answer (score 2):

```
    def http_code = sh(
        returnStdout: true,
        label: "checking myrest.api.com",
        script: """curl -X GET --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
               --header 'Accept: application/json' \
               -H 'Authorization: Bearer oosfjwejowjefojwoejfowoefjwojefwefweofjwo' \
               https://myrest.api.com -o /dev/null -w '%{http_code}'"""
        ).trim()
```